# How to include/import an entire JS file with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am new to Webpack, but I have a habit of building my web apps in the following manner:

1. Declare a global variable for the project.
2. Create several JS files that use the global variable to declare functions and variables
3. Link these separate js files in the HTML file, and combine them when going to production.

For example my first JS file would be "init.js":

```
let FP = {}; // Global Object
```

My second would be "processing.js":

```
FP.addNumbers = function(a, b){
  return a+b;
}
```

The HTML would include:

```
 <script src="init.js"></script> 
 <script src="processing.js"></script>
```

Then in production I use a node plugin I wrote to parse the HTML page and combine all the JS files into one.

I want to do something similar with Webpack, but the only way I found to combine files is with "include". Which requires each file use a separate variable name.

I literally just want to dump the contents of my separate JS files into init.js. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use Webpack to bundle your code, the *right* approach to something like this would be to take advantage of modular imports and exports to coordinate data between modules, otherwise the use of Webpack isn't really doing anything for you.

For example, here, try the following:

```
// index.js
import { addFns } from './addFns.js';

const FP = {};
window.FP = FP; // use this if the object needs to be global
addFns(FP);
```

```
// addFns.js
export const addFns = (FP) => {
  FP.addNumbers = function(a, b){
    return a+b;
  }
};
```

Then, Webpack can create the complete bundle with only a single `.js` file as output automatically, and it'll be ready for production with any more post-processing.

Comment: I almost got your answer working, but I should mention that I'm using Gutenberg in Wordpress and building into their system so I'm not really making anything "global", as my "FP" object is really just an import. 

With that said using your syntax I get everything to build without errors, however the functions on "addFns.js" are not available. Is this because FP is not a true global object?

Comment: Where are the functions being called? Do you have client-side JS that does something like `FP.addNumbers(1, 2)` somewhere?

Comment: The functions are called in the "init.js" file. The "init.js" calls can't find the function in the other files.  Do i need to include them in the "FP" export somehow? The actual "FP" variable is not global, it's really a module that wordpress imports, so everything is self contained.

Comment: You need to import the dependencies - like in the code in the answer, `import { addFns } from './addFns.js';`.

Comment: I did add that code in the index.js file, and it builds without errors. However when I run it in the browser the code fails and the console error states "o.addNumbers is not defined". For some reason the minification part of the build (which wordpress sets up) doesn't seem to connect that the FP variable preceding "addNumbers" is not supposed to have it's name changed.

Comment: The name *shouldn't* be an issue if the process is set up as you say it is, I think. If the `FP` object is imported, it can be imported and given any name in your script, and adding properties to it will add the properties to whatever the object comes from as well. To debug this, we'll need to see more about where FP is defined in the other code, and where the `addNumbers` method is being called.